# Skinny guy with belly fat

Tags: bellyfat

I am 5.8" and 67k. My chest is 38" bt belly at the middle 34, which is full of fat in lower abdomen. It seems really bad. I do not need a six pack but a lean abdomen. Plz help me to get rid of the belly...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot target fat burn to one specific part of your body. The only thing you can do is lose weight and eventually it will come off. I would recommend lifting some weights and making sure you get in enough protein so you don't lose muscle while you lose the fat you want to lose

Answer (score 1):

As yisrael said in his answer, so-called "spot reduction" through exercise is now generally regarded as a myth and impossible. But there can be other factors that affect fat distribution and how easily it accumulates. There's multiple studies showing an inverse relation between testosterone levels and abdominal fat, although some of it is specifically visceral fat (which can still add to waist size). Perhaps you should get your testosterone levels checked and see if they fall within normal levels.

That said, you're slightly taller than me and the same weight. I've been strength training for over a year and also still have quite a bit of abdominal fat to lose. So I'd say you probably just need to bring the body fat percentage down.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a lot of visceral fat in the abdomen, and round the heart which may explain the shape. This should be of some concern. The answer is the same however , regardless of the motives, be they vanity/pride or concern for health. More fat burning activity, and less fat producing eating, simple as that!
David form Cornwall U.K

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some advice for your problem (kinda got the same) :

- Don't starve yourselfs. Eat enough, but good nutriments. If you eat too much or bad aliments, you will take weights. But if you don't eat enough, you will loose some fat only temporally. Once you will eat a little more again, your body will stack more fat, just in case of another starvation. Just by eating proper meal, you can get ride of your problem.
- Don't try to do abs exercises everyday. The key is not training your abs, but to burn fat. You can't loose fat only on a part of your body. Try some cardio, like running, bicycle... Or some weight lifting move, to reinforce your body and gain muscles.